# Постановка знака препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

> Ты говорил, что прочитал первую книгу этого автора **(?)** будешь читать следующие?

Какой знак следует поставить?

Answer (score 5):

Надо поставить точку в конце косвенной речи и начать новое предложение с заглавной буквы.

> Ты говорил, что прочитал первую книгу этого автора. Будешь читать следующие?

Тогда это будет нормальная речь. Я,возможно,вызову некоторое недовольство, но хочу обратить ваше внимание, что предложение содержит законченную мысль. Первая мысль о том, что человек прочитал первую книгу. Вторая – интерес о продолжении чтения. Нельзя весь текст тянуть в одно предложение.

Comment: Несогласен. Это может быть одна фраза, тогда запятая будет уместна.

Comment: И можете привести пример из классики? Дать ссылку на теоретический источник, где говорится, что к косвенному предложению можно через запятую прилепить прямой вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая неуместна, скорее лучше поставить тире, предложение бессоюзное, и вторая часть , в некотором роде, вытекает из первой.